# Is the order of 2-torsion of Shafarevich-Tate group of $E/\mathbb{Q}$ always a square?

Tags: nt.number-theory

While  we know that the Shafarevich-Tate group of an elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ has square-order if it is finite, what can we say about the 2-torsion part in general, without assuming the finiteness? In particular, is it known that the $2$-part of Sha has to be of the form $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{2t}$ for some non-negative integer $t$, even without assumption of finiteness of Sha?

Comment: I don't know of a general theorem that would exclude Sha to be equal to $\mathbb{Q} /\mathbb{Z} $.

Comment: Squareness of the 2-torsion part is open. This plays an important role (over number fields) in the work of Mazur and Rubin on H10 for rings of integers.